# MFC XML Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, mfc

Can I serialize C++ class object to XML file using MFC Serialization. I found libraries like Boost, XML Foundation to perform this but I don't want to use any third party lib.

Is it possible in MFC C++ serialization or using any other core/native lib. Please help on this.

Comment: If you don't want to use a 3rd party library I guess you'll be writing this library yourself?

Answer (score 1):

MFC does not have any native Xml serialization.  You're either going to have to roll your own, or use a 3rd-party library.  Why you have set yourself this false limitation is entirely unknown.

If it is size, or a dependency issue you are concerned about, I recommend [TinyXml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) which you can include directly in to your C++ project and therefore have no dependencies and excellent Xml reading and writing.  Note that this won't serialize an object by default, you'll have to use the class to write the Xml out yourself.

Alternatively you can look [at this link in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11426/XML-Serialization-for-C-objects) on Xml serialization.  Once again, this will require effort on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! Boost is good option but I can't use it right now.. I am looking into TinyXml and MSXML to parse the XML also I need to do serialization and deserialization at my own.